# Backbone model structure?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to track a collection of messages to a user model, at first I figured this would be a great model structure.

```
var myModel = {
    _id: 798698,
    username: "John",
    message: {
        message1: "Some cool messsage",
        message2: "I'm mad Ohio State lost"
    }
}
```

Then I figure if I want to render all the messages from all the users in order from old to new, I could add a time stamp. That would mean I would need to extend the model.

```
var myModel = {
    _id: 798698,
    username: "John",
    message: {
        message1: {message: "Some cool messsage", sent: "3/22/2014 12:20"},
        message2: {message: "I'm mad Ohio State lost", sent: "3/22/2014 12:21"}
    }
}
```

To me this is a good structure but what do I know, I am new.

This brings up some issues with backbone, though. If I had a collection view for all the messages, the itemView for the single models would each be wrapped in an `el`. So I could loop the message object above using handle bars, but it would render like this.

```
<div class="model">

    <div class="message">
        John: Some cool message
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        John: I'm mad Ohio State lost
    </div>

</div>
```

You see the above is wrapped, so that means if there was another users model.

```
var myModel2 = {
    _id: 798698,
    username: "Scottie",
    message: {
        message1: "Hey guys",
        message2: "I am the SEC player of the year."
    }
}
```

The view would not render a list of messages but blocks of models, like this.

```
<div class="model">

    <div class="message">
        John: Some cool message
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        John: I'm mad Ohio State lost
    </div>

</div>

<div class="model">

    <div class="message">
        Scottie: Hi Guys
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        Scottie: I am the SEC player of the year.
    </div>

</div>
```

I am trying to think of a structure where I can render a list, and order by time sent.

So for example if the convo went... John, Scottie, John, Scottie... I could render like this.

```
<div class="message">
    John: Some cool message
</div>
<div class="message">
    Scottie: Hi Guys
</div>
<div class="message">
    John: I'm mad Ohio State lost
</div>
<div class="message">
    Scottie: I am the SEC player of the year.
</div>
```

So should I create two collections and associate the messages model to the user model, or is there a way to build the model the way I was and get it to play with backbone nicely. I'm up for whichever is better and I would like a brief explanation why. That would be so great fellow developers!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Backbone.Relational :

http://backbonerelational.org/

Comment: So this is the way to go? Okay I trust you, I actually was advised to use this on another project, I just didn't want to learn this plugin, but I guess this is a very useful one. So it's better to associate than directly add the messages into the model?

Comment: I dont want to fill the database with a collection of message models, that could create 1k+ documents.

Comment: dont worry,just test it.Or you could wire your objects yourself but why do it when there is already a tool for that ;)

Comment: True.. Looking at the docs, I am already confused with one thing, I failed to mention I am using marionette, I just got into that and I noticed when you use relational you extend the model similar to how you would in marionette.. I cant double extend a model to work with both can I?

Comment: Maybe marionette has a feature for relational like data lol? I did just get into it, but still how would I double extend maybe I am looking at it in the wrong way :)

Comment: Maybe I just use relational on a specific model and marionette for everything else, but things like this is why I am scared to pick up plugins. Seems like a lot of detours. I should pick this up though.

Comment: Did a quick google search maybe this is what I am looking for? A composite view.. https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md